# Is it acceptable to delete a question that already has upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, deleted-questions

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62027/would-there-be-a-halachic-reason-to-stone-jesus-for-saying-what-jws-believe-he-s?noredirect=1#comment170497_62027) was deleted after I answered it and received upvotes. This is frowned upon on SF&F SE, and I assume that the same rules apply here.

If the question was off topic, shouldn't it have been closed as such, rather than being deleted?  It seems unfair to deny answerers of rep they have already earned, and to delete an answer that required a good amount of time and effort.

Comment: I would be happy if I were given the chance to copy my answer and save it on my computer.  I'm proud of it, and I'd like to hang on to it for future reference.

Comment: You should be able to see the answer via [this link](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62030/472).  If you can't, please let me know and I'll get you a copy.  Meanwhile, I'm hoping those who were involved will answer your question here.

Comment: There was no answer with positive score at the time of deletion.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - No luck.  I got the "this question was voluntarily deleted by its owner" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was deleted by its asker and only he can say why he deleted it. Note that the Stack Exchange software allows any question author to delete his question [so long as](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) it has no more than one answer and that answer has no more upvotes than downvotes. In this case, the only answer was yours, and it the same number of upvotes and downvotes, so the question author could delete the question. If you wish to change the Stack Exchange rule, I suggest you raise propose as much on [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com) (because, there, more people will see your proposal, suggest improvements to it, and me-too it), after checking that your proposal hsn't been made there already. Perhaps you can present a convincing argument that Mi Yodeya should follow a practice different from the one imposed by Stack Exchange, but I don't know of any reason to.